# Error: Unsupported Arg - An argument named "" is not expected here

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm fairly new to Terraform, and I come across this error:

```
Error: Unsupported argument
    on replication_configs line 251, in module "s3_bucket_module":
```

Here's my module leading up to line 251:

```
module "s3_bucket_module" {
    source = "publicmodule.net"
    version = "1.0.0"
    common = local.common
    region = var.region
    is_enabled = var.s3bucket_enabled
    iamrolearn = [data.aws_iam_role.secret.arn]
    replication_config = {
        role = aws_iam_role.replication.arn
        rules = [{
        id = "everything-without-filters"
        status = "enabled"
        destination = {
            bucket = data.aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket_module.arn
            storage_class = "STANDARD"
        }
    },]
  }
}
```

Snippet of s3_bucket_module variables.tf

```
variable "replication_config" {
    describe = "Map containing cross-region replication configs."
    type = any
    default = {}
}
```

Snippet of project variables.tf

```
variable "replication_config" {
    describe = "Map containing cross-region replication configs."
    type = any
    default = {}
}
```

Any guidance would most certainly be appreciated as I originally thought that perhaps I needed to add the replication_config variable to my project variables.tf file instead of just in the s3_bucket_module.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but `describe` should be `description`. I'd guess that 251 is the `describe` line. https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/values/variables.html

Comment: What is the full error message?

Comment: Which line is 251?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the input parameters for the module. Seems like the module doesn't have an input parameter for replication_config